# Let $L : K$ be a field extension such that $[L:K]=2$. Show that $L:K$ is a normal extension.

Tags: field-theory

Let $L : K$ be a field extension such that $[L:K]=2$. Show that $L:K$ is a normal extension. Show that for any $n\ge 2$, there exists an extension $L:Q$ that is not normal and $[L:Q]=n$.

Comment: I assume you mean $n>2$, not $n\geq 2$, otherwise the second statement would contradict the first.  Also, what progress have you made in the problem?

Comment: **Hint:** a subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

Comment: Dear @Berci: I have no idea of what your  hint means, since there is no group in sight of which to take a subgroup of index $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $L\colon K$ is normal if, and only if, every irreducible polynomial over $K$ which has at least one root in $L$ factors over $L$.

So take $p(x)$ an irreducible polynomial over $K$ such that for some $\lambda\in L$, $p(\lambda)=0$.

Either $\deg(p(x))=1$ or $\deg(p(x))\ge 2$. I'll handle the second case only.

Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\lambda$ over $K$. It can't happen that $\lambda \in K$, why?

So $[K(\lambda)\colon K]>1$, thus $2=[L\colon K]=[L\colon K(\lambda)][K(\lambda )\colon K]$ and it follows that $L=K(\lambda)$. Therefore $\deg(m(x))=2$ and there exist $b,c\in K$ such that $m(x)=x^2+bx+c$. On the other hand, for some $\mu$ in the splitting field of $m(x)$, it holds that $m(x)=(x-\lambda)(x-\mu)$. Equate $x^2+bx+c=(x-\lambda)(x-\mu)$ to conclude that $\mu\in L$ and hence infer that $m(x)$ factors over $L$. Finally conclude that $p(x)$ factors over $L$.

Therefore $[L\colon K]$ is normal.

For the second part take $L=\mathbb Q(\root n\of 2)$. You should check this works for $n>2$.